# Create column summary in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, lookup

```
ACTION_NAME      ACTION_REASON         CH      PT    SK    CZ   UK
    Add Name         Name Change       No            Yes    ?   Yes
    Add Job          Job Change        Yes           No    No   ?
    Add Position     Postion Change    Yes           No    No   ?
```

I would need to to create 4 extra columns named:

- Countries Using this Action Reason
- Countries not Using this Action Reason
- Countries with Question Mark
- Countries that didn't answer (blank values)

In front of those columns, I would need to consolidate the countries that answered Yes, No, NO ANSWER, ? for each of those action/action reason looking like this (example of first row):

```
ACTION_NAME      ACTION_REASON      CH     PT      SK      CZ   UK          Countries using this action   Countries not Using this Action   Countries with Question Mark   Countries Blank
Add Name         Name Change        No             Yes     ?    Yes                          SK, UK                            CH                             CZ                     PT
```

What would be the best solution to create those consolidated columns?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a mapping dict to rename values (Yes, No, ?, '') then use `melt` to flatten your dataframe and finally `pivot_table` to reshape it:

```
MAPPING = {'Yes': 'Countries using this action',
           'No': 'Countries not Using this Action',
           '?': 'Countries with Question Mark',
           np.nan: 'Countries Blank'}

df1 = (df.melt(['ACTION_NAME', 'ACTION_REASON']).replace({'value': MAPPING})
         .pivot_table('variable', ['ACTION_NAME', 'ACTION_REASON'], 'value',
                      aggfunc=', '.join, sort=False)[MAPPING.values()]
         .rename_axis(columns=None).set_index(df.index))
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    ACTION_NAME   ACTION_REASON   CH   PT  SK   CZ  UK Countries using this action Countries not Using this Action Countries with Question Mark Countries Blank
0      Add Name     Name Change   No  Yes   ?  Yes NaN                      PT, CZ                              CH                           SK              UK
1       Add Job      Job Change  Yes   No  No    ? NaN                          CH                          PT, SK                           CZ              UK
2  Add Position  Postion Change  Yes   No  No    ? NaN                          CH                          PT, SK                           CZ              UK
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting the error "TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'"

Comment: `sort` parameter is available since Pandas >= 1.3.0. It doesn't matter, you can remove it after all, it does not change anything. However, you should upgrade your version of Pandas if you can.

Comment: Now the error I receive is
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 295 rows, received array of length 296
Do you know what it should be? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is the output of `df.value_counts(['ACTION_NAME', 'ACTION_REASON']).loc[lambda x: x>1]`

Comment: If you can share your data, it will help to understand.

Comment: I added a big portion of the data, please check if that is enough. The last code you provided counted the number of occurances but do not list the countries in the columns as I needed

Comment: Yes I can, how could I do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246222/discussion-between-paulo-cortez-and-corralien).